# Range Slider styling doesn't work on edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

My CSS style for the range slider doesn't work on Edge. How can I fix the Problem?

I searched on the web for a solution. And added some codes but still not working.

```
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;  
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: #33A2D9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #33A2D9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*I added this to fix for edge but it doesn't work */
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb{
    width: 15px !important;
    height: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    background: #33A2D9 !important;
    cursor: pointer  !important;;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background: #d3d3d3 !important;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background: #d3d3d3 !important;
}
```

What it should look like (for example on Firefox):
[image]

What it look like on edge:[image]

Comment: Add a full example (preferably directly in the snippet editor or a codepen or something) if you want folks to help debug something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *"mistake"* (if we can call it that) was giving the input a `background`. You want to give it `background-color` of `transparent` and give the `-track` the desired shade.

Also, as a minor side note and general rule, avoid using `background` instead of `background-color`. It is shorter, but it sets a bunch of other `background-` properties, which you normally don't care about but are a source of common bugs.

Since it tends to be repetitive, I wrote it in SCSS:

```scss
$input-height: 16px;
$track-height: 6px;
$thumb-bg: #33A2D9;
$track-bg: #d3d3d3;
@mixin slider-thumb {
  width: $input-height;
  height: $input-height;
  border-radius: $input-height/2;
  background-color: $thumb-bg;
  appearance: none;
}

@mixin slider-track {
  height: $track-height;
  border-radius: $track-height/2;
  background-color: $track-bg;
  appearance: none;
}

.slider[type=range] {
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: $input-height;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  &::-webkit-slider- {
    &runnable-track {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      @include slider-track;
    }
    &thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      @include slider-thumb;
      margin-top: -($input-height - $track-height)/2;
    }
  }
  &::-moz-range- {
    &track {
      @include slider-track;
    }
    &thumb {
      @include slider-thumb;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
  &::-ms- {
    &track {
      @include slider-track;
    }
    &fill-upper {
      @include slider-track;
    }
    &fill-lower {
      @include slider-track;
    }
    &thumb {
      @include slider-thumb;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Resulting in the following CSS:

```css
.slider[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider[type=range]:hover, .slider[type=range]:focus, .slider[type=range]:active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.slider[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #33A2D9;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.slider[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.slider[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #33A2D9;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.slider[type=range]::-ms-track {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.slider[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.slider[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.slider[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #33A2D9;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type=range class=slider>
```

Playground [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/arpj5tcd/).

Comment: THANK YOU so much for the detailed help! I could only work on it now, cause I was on vacation. So I couldnt check the answer before. When you tell me how, i can also give you more points! TY Again!